# Error when using require_relative in an executable file

Tags: ruby

This is my executable file, named execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative '../config/environment.rb'

x = Scraper.new 
Item.clear_all
x.create_entire_menu
x.start
```

environment.rb looks like this:

```
require 'pry'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

require_relative '../lib/cfaprotein.rb'
require_relative '../lib/item.rb'
require_relative '../lib/scraper.rb'
require_relative '../lib/clifunctions.rb'
```

environment.rb is in config

execute is in bin

cfaprotein.rb is in lib with item.rb, scraper.rb and clifunctions.rb

cfaprotein.rb has the following at the top:

```
require "cfaprotein/version"
```

the other three items in lib have the following at the top:

```
require_relative './environment.rb'

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pry'
```

config, lib and bin are all in cfaprotein inside of Development.

When I enter:

```
ruby bin/execute
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- cfaprotein/version (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 
`require'
    from /home/swarbrick85/Development/cfaprotein/lib/cfaprotein.rb:1:in 
`<top (required)>'
    from /home/swarbrick85/Development/cfaprotein/config/environment.rb:5:in 
`require_relative'
    from /home/swarbrick85/Development/cfaprotein/config/environment.rb:5:in 
`<top (required)>'
    from bin/execute:3:in `require_relative'
    from bin/execute:3:in `<main>'
```

What in my code is incorrect and preventing this executable file in bin from executing?

Comment: Do you have a `cfaprotein.rb` file inside of `config`? It's looking for one but can't find it.

Comment: I added information. cfaprotein is in lib. Thank you.

Comment: in the string following 'require_relative' does it matter how many '.' are at the beginning of the string?

Comment: @swarbrick85: of course, it matters. `.` is "current dir" and `..` is "parent dir"

Comment: @swarbrick85 You have to at least ask a question. If you are not sure what to ask, then this is not the right place for you.

Comment: @sawa well i can think of questions: is my execute file properly accessing my environment file? Is my environment file properly accessing the 4 files it's supposed to be accessing? If not, why?

Comment: Write that in the main text of the question, not in the comment.

Comment: And from the next time, don't think about what to ask after you have posted a question; think before doing it.

Comment: thank you @Sergio Tulentsev.

Comment: @sawa done as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question provided a different error message. The new error message points to the same type of problem, which is that when using both `require` and `require_relative` you need to understand how the methods work and where your files are located and how to navigate a tree structure.

The link for `require_relative` is posted but you should also look at [require](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require) (which is a little more verbose)

Your error message is pretty clear if you weed out the cruft:

```
cannot load such file -- cfaprotein/version
from /home/swarbrick85/Development/cfaprotein/lib/cfaprotein.rb:1
```

This would, I believe, expect a `version.rb` file to live in `lib/cfaprotein/version.rb`, assuming the `lib` folder is configured somewhere (maybe a gemspec file, maybe somewhere else) to be in your `$LOAD_PATH`

If `version.rb` isn't in the `lib/cfaprotein` folder, move it there and try it.

If it is in that folder, and still doesn't work, change the require to `require_relative './cfaprotein/version.rb'` after moving the file.

Answer (score 2):

[require_relative(string)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) does the following (emphasis mine):

> Ruby tries to load the library named string relative to the
>   **requiring file's path**.

Since you're trying to require files from `environment.rb` using `require_relative './foo'` it's looking for those files in the *same* directory as `environment.rb` (`config` I believe).